# How to cast back Boost::thread::id from string?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

So I casted `boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(boost::this_thread::get_id())` this thread id to string. Now I wonder is it possible to turn it back into thread::id?

Comment: @JackOfAllTrades: my id to string? Yes [here](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/detail?r=1443) and, you know, it speeds thing up a lot! (10%) (iterate thru map of strings rather than thru map of thread::id's). But after that you can understend that you just might need one more thing - interrupt threads links to which you can access only in form of string... and to call ->interrupt you need real thread::id - not string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned calling ->interrupt I assume you need the boost::thread object, not the boost::thread:id object.

Your best option might be to create a mapping of string - boost::thread objects when spawning threads.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use 'boost::lexical_cast' to cast a string to a int/short/the_type_you_want. It would look like this :

```
boost::lexical_cast<int>(string_of_thread_id);
```